# How to rollback a specific directory in ZFS snapshot?

Tags: linux, backup, archiving, zfs, snapshot

Is it possible to rollback to a certain directory within a snapshot? For example, given the snapshot `tank/home@snapshot_week_01` can I rollback to something like `tank/home/louis@snapshot_week_01` without rolling back all of the other files directories within `tank/home`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question "Is it possible", the answer is **no**. ZFS snapshots have no concept of files, folders, or anything else, it is a block level snapshot of the entire filesystem.

You can however browse a snapshot and access individual files, as indicated in duenni's answer, or you can clone a snapshot giving you a second copy of the filesystem without rolling back the first.

Answer (score 17):

In this case I would go to `/tank/home/.zfs/snapshot/snapshot_week_01` and pull out the data you need.

See [Displaying and Accessing ZFS Snapshots](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbiqe/index.html) on Oracle's website for details.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question as asked is **no;** snapshots are per file system and you can only operate on the whole file system when working with the snapshot. So if you roll back to a previous snapshot, that affects the entire file system.

The way to restore specific files or directories from a ZFS snapshot is to navigate into the snapshot directory and then copy the files out of the snapshot, using something like `cp -av snapshotfile /home/louis/myfile`.

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't really understand duenni's answer until reading yours and @dasdfdsaq's. But looks like yours was a tiny bit later!

Comment: @Louis You're welcome; I'm glad I was able to help. (And while it's certainly your choice which answer to accept, you shouldn't feel pressured into accepting the answer that came first. Instead, you should accept the one that *you* found most helpful *to you*.)

Comment: P.S. With a properly configured Samba setup on top of ZFS on Linux, you can also right click on a folder from a Windows client and use the "Previous versions" functionality

Comment: I have come accustomed to using `rsync -a` for this use case. If only a few files in a directory have changed since the snapshot, this prevents from copying more data than necessary. Deleting and re-creating a file with the same content will allocate additional storage.